# How to show loaded item in the list when rest of the items are being loaded in flutter future builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching a list of data and I would like to show the loaded items in the Future builder's list view while the rest of the items are being loaded, is it possible?

I have a `ListView Builder` inside a `FutureBuilder`, The Api call fetches 15 items and assigns to the list here `FinalDataList`

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('All Artworks',textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    ),

    body:  FutureBuilder(
        future: dataFuture,
        builder: (context,snapshot){
         if(finalDataList.length > 0){

          return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: (){
                this._showToast(context);
                return this.refreshHomePage();

              },

              child:  ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: finalDataList!=null?finalDataList.length:0,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                        return new Card(

                           child: Text(finalDataList[index]['title']),
                        );
                       },
                      ),
                     );

      }else{

         return new  Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            ),
           );
        }

       }
   ),
 );
```

What happens now is the entire widget of lists with 15 items only shows after all of them are loaded. How can I show the loaded items first while the remaining items are being loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of futures and use `ListView.builder` to await on each one individually.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: futureList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => FutureBuilder(
    future: futureList[index],
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator(...);
      } else {
        return Center(...);
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

How you convert `dataFuture` into `futureList` will depend on how exactly you are creating `dataFuture` in the first place.